Adding Component In Placeholder Not Working in Experience Editor
I am trying to add a component under placeholder in experience editor, I am getting error " Could not find the rendering in the HTML loaded from server" , attached the screens.
"renderingDomElement" is null so getting the error.
Its Sitecore 9.3, Sitecore JSS 13.0.0, React frontend
When i debug in browser, I see that element for newly adding component is not generated, i see this has been generated in other Sitecore JSS project. I assume because element is not generating and so required ID value is not present in page html so it throws null for renderingDomElement.


Sitecore Version: 9.3,
JSS Version:13.0.0.0
To Reproduce:
Open page in experience editor, click on "add here", selected component in "Select a Rendering" wizard, select datasource, click on okay, then the error will be displayed.
Expected Behavior:
We should be able to add component in experience editor, by following steps : click on "add here" select rendering, select datasource, click ok, should be able to add component on the page.
